# How to get partecipants from channel id with Telethon

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to use GetParticipantsRequest()  with first Param as documentation:

> channel   - InputChannel  - Anything entity-like will work if the library can find its Input version (e.g., usernames, Peer, User or Channel objects, etc.)

My code:

```
newInputChannel = InputChannel(channelId, channelHash)


all_participants = await client(functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest(
        newInputChannel,
        filter=types.ChannelParticipantsRecent(),
        offset=42,
        limit=100,
        hash=0
))
```

But i get the error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelInvalidError: Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by GetParticipantsRequest)

The group is PRIVATE so it doesn't have a USERNAME but i anyway get the GROUP_ID and the GROUP_HASH, how can i get the list of all members?

Thank you

Comment: See [`client.iter_participants()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants).

Comment: Are you the channel admin?

Comment: @Lonami 
I get the error:
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelInvalidError: Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by GetFullChannelRequest)
Using:client.iter_participants(InputChannel(ChannelID, channelHash), aggressive=True)